What OpenStreetMap data does Google maps use to choose bike routes?
Hi I am trying to find out what road attributes tagged on OpenStreetMap cause Google maps to choose or avoid road segments when routing bikes. I want to implement some low cost interventions to improve bicycle route finding within my city to make cycling more accessible to people. Do things like "designated bike routes" marked in OpenStreetMap cause Google maps to prefer those streets for bikes when finding routes? If so I'm planning on trying to push city council to adopt a bike route map I am working on so that I can then in good faith add that info into OpenStreetMap and hopefully get Google maps and similar programs to stop recommending busy streets with no accommodations for bike.
I have asked the OpenStreetMap community and they had no definitive answer as to what Google maps does and does not consider.
